2002 Honda Civic EP3 Type R (JDM) - faulty MICU Swap (multiplex control unit)
I have a faulty MICU from a 2002 EP3 Civic Type R (JDM).  The MICU has the typical problems:

No dome light when car door is open
No key chime
No working AC
No intermittent wipers
Parking brake light stays on all the time

I'm not able to source the original MICU (Part# 38200-S5T-J12).
I swapped an unit in from a Euro EP3 Civic Type R, the electrical problems are solved, but now the car won't start (it does crank)
Does anyone know if I need to swap an EEPROM or re-program something? I'm pretty sure I don't have an immobilizer on this car, there is no flashing green key.
Please help!

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I take it the MICU is like a BCM in a lot of other vehicles?

Did the car start with the original MICU? Are  original keys plain or have remote buttons, indicating factory antitheft is part of Civics? Tried other Honda forums than the one you joined?

Yes, the car starts with original MICU. The key is plain, no fob.  It doesn't appear to have immobilizer or a factory alarm
